# listings - Nodejs support?

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I would like to use some code block for a report.
The only problem : I didn't find inside listings for the language I used (Nodejs).

Can you help me ?

PS: I check inside the listings package : http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/start/listings.pdf

Comment: Nodejs builds on JavaScript. I don't know, whether this is supported by listings. Try `minted`.

Comment: @TeXnician apparently it still isn't, but we've got an old question with answers that do much of the work.

Comment: still not ? The post was in 2014 .... I just hope there was someone who has done it

Comment: This gist has ES6 syntax (check comment) : https://gist.github.com/Geruhn/3d21f60a869457373d84 . maybe extend this example with nodejs syntax ?

Comment: Note that the version of the manual you link to is ancient, the version in TeX Live 2016 is 1.6, dated June 2015. Node.js support has not been added, but in general it would be better to check the latest version, via e.g. https://ctan.org/ or http://texdoc.net/. Or type `texdoc listings` in a terminal/command line on your computer.